# How to add two elements in single list view row without using custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a project where I don't have much time to do custom work. (Im creating a custom row layout with a custom adapter)

How do I add two elements values in a single row, without having to create a custom layout for the rows and a custom adapter?

Comment: use *ArrayAdapter* instead.

Comment: @HasanuzzamanMamun please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy:

- you create a custom model that holds your object for each item.
- Use an `ArrayList` as the data source
- Create a custom layout for each row
- use `ArrayAdapter` to show data to the ListView

[Please visit this link for a tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

If you don't want to use a custom layout, you can use Android's default row items. See [this link](https://robgibbens.com/androids-built-in-list-item-layouts/) for details about default layouts.

Comment: See the question , i dont want to use custom layout or custom adapter .

Comment: You said you don't want to use custom adapter, didn't mention custom layout

Comment: look , simply i just want to add 2 elements in a single row without using custom supports .

Comment: Answer has been updated. Please see it. I hope it solves your problem